# Javascript function call in PHP before <head> tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have a webpage that uses PHP that must be output before any code is called.  In another part of my PHP I need to call a JavaScript function for displaying a message on certain user actions.  Is there a way I can call my JavaScript function at the top of my page? I'd rather keep all the PHP together as currently it looks like this;

```
<?php
     ...Code that must be called first...
?>
...<head></head>....
<?php
     if (PHPFunction()){
         echo "<script>MyJSFunction();</script>";
     }
?>
```

To me it looks messy having it this way.  How can I avoid this?

EDIT:

To make my intentions more clear.  The JavaScript function I'm using will display a pop up message, giving the user feedback on actions they are performing.  For example, if they upload a file,  if move_uploaded_file() is successful, this message gets called.  The browser complained when I had my bottom code in the top part saying that my JavaScript function was not defined.  When I moved it under it was all good, apart from now looking messy.

Comment: How about `<head><script>window.onload=function() { myFunction(); }</script></head>`

Comment: Create a script with HTML and drop `<?="MyJSFunction();" ?>` somewhere. it won't look too ugly.

Comment: The second part with the echo can just be plan HTML. There is no PHP in that code at all. Also, PHP is completely executed server side before the page content is sent to the browser. JavaScript is executed in the browser when the page has loaded. They don't take turns, no matter in which order they are on the page. Maybe you know this, but your question suggests to me you don't.

Comment: Sorry I have that code inside PHP if statements, so it gets called on certain conditions

Comment: In general, when you are mixing PHP and HTML you will quite often have multiple pieces of PHP code. There is hardly a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jQuery ?
if you are, have you try this code:

```
<?
     move_uploaded_file(source, destination);
     echo "<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        alert ('file successfullu  uploaded');
        });
        </script>";
?>
```